# Reshaping wide to long with multiple row

Tags: r, transpose

This is a part of my data frame:

```
name      value_1  value_2  value_3
 AK          x       X
 AK          y       Y
 AK          m       M         B
 HU          z       Z
 HU          a       A
 HU          f       F         C
 KO          b       B
 KO          c       C
 KO          d       D         B
```

I need:

```
num   AK    HU   KO
 1    x      z   b
 1    X      Z   B
 2    y      a   c
 2    Y      A   C
 3    m      f   d
 3    M      F   D
 3    B      C   B
```

In words; I have values for person AK, HU, and KO (and many others). All rated the same - hence the number of rows for each unique-ID is same and the number of values will also be the same.
In this part of the data frame 1 and 2 have two values, 3 has 3 values for each person.
It is actually forced choice task and hence values in value_1:2 are actually 1 and 0 only but I have replaced them with a-Z to show the the sorting.

I tried :

```
library(reshape2)
long <- melt(df, id.vars = c("name"))
```

that doesn't do the trick however, as all are added below each other, while I need them to be reshaped to long according to their ID (name), but the different name-IDs would then need to be placed in separate columns next to each other.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the input shown in the Note below, run the `melt` shown in the question and then transform `value_1`, `value_2` and `value_3` to just 1, 2 and 3 and also add a `subseq` column to distinguish rows that otherwise have the same key.  Get rid of empty `value` rows and convert back to wide form using `dcast` removing the `subseq` column:

```
library(reshape2)

long <- melt(DF, id.var = "name") # from question
long2 <- transform(long, num = gsub("\\D", "", variable),
          subseq =  ave(1:nrow(m), name, variable, FUN = seq_along),
          variable = NULL)
long3 <- subset(long2, value != "")
wide <- dcast(subseq + num ~ name, data = long3, value.var = "value")[-1]
```

giving:

```
> wide
  num AK HU KO
1   1  x  z  b
2   2  X  Z  B
3   1  y  a  c
4   2  Y  A  C
5   1  m  f  d
6   2  M  F  D
7   3  B  C  B
```

Check against expected:

```
identical(wide, expected)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
name      value_1  value_2  value_3
 AK          x       X
 AK          y       Y
 AK          m       M         B
 HU          z       Z
 HU          a       A
 HU          f       F         C
 KO          b       B
 KO          c       C
 KO          d       D         B"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, fill = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

We have assumed that `num` is a factor and the other data is character  -- we can't tell what was intended since the input is not given in reproducible form in the question.

```
expected <- structure(list(num = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = 
c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), AK = c("x", 
"X", "y", "Y", "m", "M", "B"), HU = c("z", "Z", "a", "A", "f", 
"F", "C"), KO = c("b", "B", "c", "C", "d", "D", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Update 2

This variation uses 0/1 data and integer `num`:

```
set.seed(123)
# test data
DF2 <- data.frame(name = DF$name, 
           value_1 = rbinom(9, 1, .5), 
           value_2 = rbinom(9, 1, .5),
           value_3 = ifelse(DF[, 4] == "", NA, rbinom(9, 1, .5)))

long <- melt(DF2, id.var = "name")
long2 <- subset(long, !is.na(value))
long3 <- transform(long2, num = as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", variable)),
           subseq =  ave(1:nrow(long2), name, variable, FUN = seq_along),
           variable = NULL)
wide <- dcast(subseq + num ~ name, data = long3, value.var = "value")[-1]
```

giving:

```
> wide
  num AK HU KO
1   1  0  1  1
2   2  0  1  1
3   3  1  1  1
4   1  1  1  1
5   2  1  1  0
6   1  0  0  1
7   2  0  0  0
```

Comment: thx, though your output is different from the one I stated above.
I would need the column under each name ID to list row-wise, instead of column-wise.

Comment: Have fixed and added a check at the end to ensure that it gives identical answer to that expected in question.

Comment: I understand that my information was not enough, so I edited it above. Actually the values are only 0 and 1 but so that I could show the reordering I need, I used letters.

Answer (score 0):

I had to include a few small extra steps to get this done since you wanted the output in a specific order, but this should do it:

```
long<-melt(df, id.vars=c("name"), value.var=c("value_1","value_2","value_3"))
long$variable<-c("11","21","31","11","21","31","11","21","31",
                 "12","22","32","12","22","32","12","22","32",
                 "13","23","33","13","23","33","13","23","33")
short<-dcast(long, variable ~ name)
final<-short[short$AK!="",]
final$variable<-round(as.numeric(final$variable)/10,0)
colnames(final)[1]<-"num"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx a lot! Unfortunatelly I don't get the proper order of rows. Instead of the values of the first row below each other, plus values of 2nd row, I get something differnt. Do you know what went wrong?

Comment: Okay, I misread your ask the first go around. But I edited my answer with something that gave me your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This will provide desired output:

```
 library(tidyverse)
df0=df%>%mutate(Value12=map2(value_1,value_2,c))%>%
  mutate(Value=map2(Value12,value_3,c))%>%
  select(name,Value)%>%
  unnest()%>%
  drop_na()%>%
  group_by(name)%>%
   mutate(i = row_number())%>%
  spread(name,Value)%>%
  select(-i)


df0$num=cumsum(c(toupper(df0$AK)==toupper(lag(df0$AK)),F)%>%na.omit())
> df0
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  AK    HU    KO      num
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 x     z     b         1
2 X     Z     B         1
3 y     a     c         2
4 Y     A     C         2
5 m     f     d         3
6 M     F     D         3
7 B     C     B         3
```

However you need to clarify what is the logic of populating column num. I had to assume same letter (not case sensitive) for column AK will have the same num.

Comment: To clarify; each person with a name-ID had to rate the same number of entires; so here each of them had to rate 3 groups and each group has a set number of elements (in the example either 2 or 3 elements). 

reshaping them will get rid of the grouping but retain the ordering. 
Does this clarify anything?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, here is a solution which uses `melt()` and `dcast()` from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package. `rowid(name)` is used to create row numbers for each `name` individually.

It reproduces the expected result including column `num`.

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(setDT(df)[, num := rowid(name)], id.vars = c("num", "name"))[value != ""]
dcast(long, num + rowid(name) ~ name, value.var = "value")[, name := NULL][]
```

> ```
>    num AK HU KO
> 1:   1  x  z  b
> 2:   1  X  Z  B
> 3:   2  y  a  c
> 4:   2  Y  A  C
> 5:   3  m  f  d
> 6:   3  M  F  D
> 7:   3  B  C  B
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("
name      value_1  value_2  value_3
 AK          x       X
 AK          y       Y
 AK          m       M         B
 HU          z       Z
 HU          a       A
 HU          f       F         C
 KO          b       B
 KO          c       C
 KO          d       D         B", fill = TRUE)
```